# Write a function that returns True if the object is exactly an instance of the specified class ; otherwise False

Tags: python

I started learning inheritance in Python and I'm struggling with this exercise.

I need to create a function `def is_same_class(obj, a_class):`

That will be used here:

```
a = 1
if is_same_class(a, int):
    print("{} is an instance of the class {}".format(a, int.__name__))
if is_same_class(a, float):
    print("{} is an instance of the class {}".format(a, float.__name__))
if is_same_class(a, object):
    print("{} is an instance of the class {}".format(a, object.__name__))
```

and the output should be: `1 is an instance of the class int`
but I'm getting:

```
1 is an instance of the class int
1 is an instance of the class object
```

Since all variable types inherit from the *object* class.

How can I validate only the subclass *int* and stop there?

I can only think of:

```
def is_same_class(obj, a_class):
        return isinstance(obj, a_class)
```

Which returns True for both *int* and *object*

Comment: Everything is inherited from `object` in Python, so `isinstance(variable, object)` will always return true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know if the precise type of obj is a_class (and not a subtype of a_class), then you want the [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function.

```
def is_same_class(obj, a_class):
    return type(obj) is a_class

is_same_class(1, int)    # True
is_same_class(1, object) # False
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything (well, almost) in python is an `object`. If you want to use the last `if` as a fallback (for when `a` is neither an `int` nor a `float`), you will need to use `elif`:

```
if is_same_class(a, int):
    print("{} is an instance of the class {}".format(a, int.__name__))
elif is_same_class(a, float):
    print("{} is an instance of the class {}".format(a, float.__name__))
elif is_same_class(a, object):
    print("{} is an instance of the class {}".format(a, object.__name__))
```

but then you might as well just drop the condition as it will always be true:

```
if is_same_class(a, int):
    print("{} is an instance of the class {}".format(a, int.__name__))
elif is_same_class(a, float):
    print("{} is an instance of the class {}".format(a, float.__name__))
else:
    print("{} is an instance of the class {}".format(a, object.__name__))
```